# Почему console.dir() в Firefox выдает такие результаты (кодировка UTF-8) ?

Tags: firefox, javascript, консоль

Допустим есть такой код

```
var test = {name:'Съешь ещё этих мягких французских булок'};
console.dir(test.name);
console.dir(test);
```

почему в консоль (FF 25.0) во втором случае выводится абракадабра

[image]

**Обновление**

С 26-й версии [баг](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=933347) исправлен.

Answer (score 1):

используй [firebug](https://getfirebug.com/). Там все нормально отображается.

И еще. Лучше используй console.log() вместо console.dir(). Тогда даже в дефолтной консоли все красиво отображается =) И почитай интересную [статейку](http://habrahabr.ru/post/114483/)

Comment: Суть не в том, чтобы получить ожидаемое, а в том, чтобы понять, что происходит при передаче объектов в FF по ссылке. Слово "Тест" отображается как ""5AB", т.е. формально возможно восприятие его браузером на каком-то этапе обработки как пустой строки с ошибками синтаксиса после него. Да и console, насколько я помню, детище именно FF, поэтому логично ожидать корректной работы не только console.log, но и console.dir. По второй ссылке 404.

Comment: @kaf, вторая ссылка полностью рабочая

Comment: @mountpoint, да, сейчас ссылка работает (но утром было 404), статья достойная, но ничего нового для решения своей проблемы я из нее не смог извлечь...